# Raiz cuadrada en Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

Al realizar la ejecución en un ejercicio que implica el uso de una raiz cuadrada, la cual he definido de la siguiente manera:

```
opraiz=$((($diametro * $diametro)/2))
raiz=$(echo "scale=5; sqrt($opraiz)" | bc -l)
```

Me sobrepone por pantalla el siguiente error habiendo introducido el cálculo de la raiz para el 5:

```
diametrocasaraiz.sh: 38: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: " 7.07106 * 7.07106 "
```

No se si existe otra forma de definir una raiz en bash

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: El error que te indica es que no puede hacer la operación de multiplicación. ( Entiendo que 7.07106 es el valor que tienes en diámetro. Puedes usar el comando `expr` para resolver el ejercicio? O no está permitido para hacer esta práctica?

Comment: @Jakala el comando expr no esta definido, por lo cual doy por hecho que tambien se puede utilizar, pero al implementarlo me da otro eror relacionado tambien con esta raiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash sólo maneja números enteros, así que `opraiz` también tenés que pasarlo por bc.

```
#!/bin/bash
diametro_default="7.07106"
read -p  "Ingresa Diametro($diametro_default): " diametro;
diametro=${diametro:-$diametro_default}
opraiz=$( echo "$diametro * $diametro / 2" | bc -l )
raiz=$(echo "scale=5; sqrt($opraiz)" | bc -l)
echo "$raiz"
```

Comment: Intentando su propuesta me sigue dando el mismo error, el caso de mi ejercicio es que diámetro no es siempre la cantidad fija de "7.07106" si no que puede ser cualquier cantidad preguntada previamente  al usuario

Comment: tratalo como string hasta el momento de hacer cálculos, también podes ponerle un default por las dudas ( edit: ejemplo con un read y default value )